# How can I store composed changes using Quill?

Tags: javascript, quill

I started to work with Quill, and I need to save the changes made by the user in the document, and if possible, composing them, so I don't need to store operation by operation.

To accomplish this, I am monitoring the 'text-change' event, and every operation is stored in the database of my application. From time to time (every minute), I compose the changes made in the document with a previous document state and execute a diff between the result of this composition and the previous document state, storing the result of the diff, and deleting the previous operations, because they are in the diff result.

To get the previous document state, initially I use the original document delta. Then, when a diff is stored, I just compose the original document delta with the diff's that exist in the database. For example:

Original document delta: `{"ops":[{"insert":"Evaluation Only. Created with Aspose.Words. Copyright 2003-2018 Aspose Pty Ltd.","attributes":{"size":"16px","font":"Calibri","bold":true,"color":"#FF0000"}},{"insert":"\n","attributes":{"paragraph":true,"spacing_before":"0px","spacing_after":"10.67px","indent":0,"text_indent":"0px","line_spacing":"17.27px"}},{"insert":"Test","attributes":{"size":"14.67px","font":"Calibri","color":"#000000"}},{"insert":"s","attributes":{"size":"14.67px","font":"Calibri","color":"#000000"}},{"insert":"\n","attributes":{"paragraph":true,"spacing_before":"0px","spacing_after":"10.67px","indent":0,"text_indent":"0px","line_spacing":"17.27px"}}],"page_setup":{"left_margin":"113.4px","top_margin":"94.47px","right_margin":"113.4px","bottom_margin":"94.47px"}}`

First change: `{"ops":[{"delete":80}]}`

Second change: `{"ops":[{"retain":5},{"insert":"\n","attributes":{"spacing_before":"0px","spacing_after":"10.67px","text_indent":"0px","line_spacing":"17.27px"}}]}`

Third change: `{"ops":[{"retain":6},{"insert":"A","attributes":{"color":"#000000"}}]}`

The code I am using is shown below:

```
var diffs = result.diffs;
var deltas = result.deltas;

var lastComposedDelta = null;

for (var i = 0; i < diffs.length; i++) {
    var currentDelta = newDelta(diffs[i].Value);

    if (lastComposedDelta == null) {
        lastComposedDelta = currentDelta;
    } else {
        lastComposedDelta = lastComposedDelta.compose(currentDelta);
    }
}

var composedDeltas = lastComposedDelta;

for (var i = 0; i < deltas.length; i++) {
    var currentDelta = newDelta(deltas[i].Value);

    if (composedDeltas == null) {
        composedDeltas = currentDelta;
    } else {
        composedDeltas = composedDeltas.compose(currentDelta);
    }
}

var diffDelta = composedDeltas;
if (lastComposedDelta != null) {
    diffDelta = lastComposedDelta.diff(composedDeltas);
}
```

The result of this diff is: `{"ops":[{"delete":80},{"retain":5},{"retain":1,"attributes":{"paragraph":null,"indent":null}},{"attributes":{"color":"#000000"},"insert":"A"},{"attributes":{"paragraph":true,"spacing_before":"0px","spacing_after":"10.67px","indent":0,"text_indent":"0px","line_spacing":"17.27px"},"insert":"\n"}]}`

The problem I encountered is when the user inserts a new line and indent it, for example. The delta of such operations are:

New line: `{"ops":[{"retain":8},{"insert":"\n"}]}`

Indent: `{"ops":[{"retain":9},{"retain":1,"attributes":{"indent":1}}]}`

Then, when I try to diff the document, with the code above, it gives me the error:

```
Uncaught Error: diff() called with non-document
```

Value of "lastComposedDelta": `{"ops":[{"insert":"Tests","attributes":{"size":"14.67px","font":"Calibri","color":"#000000"}},{"insert":"\n","attributes":{"spacing_before":"0px","spacing_after":"10.67px","text_indent":"0px","line_spacing":"17.27px"}},{"attributes":{"color":"#000000"},"insert":"A"},{"attributes":{"paragraph":true,"spacing_before":"0px","spacing_after":"10.67px","indent":0,"text_indent":"0px","line_spacing":"17.27px"},"insert":"\n"},{"delete":80},{"retain":5},{"retain":1,"attributes":{"paragraph":null,"indent":null}},{"insert":"A","attributes":{"color":"#000000"}},{"insert":"\n","attributes":{"paragraph":true,"spacing_before":"0px","spacing_after":"10.67px","indent":0,"text_indent":"0px","line_spacing":"17.27px"}}]}`

Value of "composedDeltas": 
`{"ops":[{"insert":"Tests","attributes":{"size":"14.67px","font":"Calibri","color":"#000000"}},{"insert":"\n","attributes":{"spacing_before":"0px","spacing_after":"10.67px","text_indent":"0px","line_spacing":"17.27px"}},{"insert":"A","attributes":{"color":"#000000"}},{"insert":"\n","attributes":{"paragraph":true,"spacing_before":"0px","spacing_after":"10.67px","indent":0,"text_indent":"0px","line_spacing":"17.27px"}},{"insert":"\n"},{"delete":80},{"retain":1,"attributes":{"indent":1}},{"retain":4},{"retain":1,"attributes":{"paragraph":null,"indent":null}},{"insert":"A","attributes":{"color":"#000000"}},{"insert":"\n","attributes":{"paragraph":true,"spacing_before":"0px","spacing_after":"10.67px","indent":0,"text_indent":"0px","line_spacing":"17.27px"}}]}`

I dig a little, and found out that the error is caused because there is a "retain" operation on the deltas used to diff, and it is not processed. So, I want to know if there is a solution for this, because I am unsure if the code I've made is the right way to do this (storing diffs of a document).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I discovered the problem with the diff function. It was because, when I initialized the editor, I was using the function `updateContents` to set the delta I had in the database to the editor. Quill always initialize the editor with a blank line. By calling the `updateContents`, it was composing the blank line with the text coming from my database. Then, when the user was changing the text, the delta from the editor was different from the delta in the database.

To fix this, I changed the function that was loading the content from the database to `setContents`. This way, the deltas from the editor and database matched.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need each individual operation, you can just update the document on the `text-change` event like so:

```
quill.on('text-change', () => {
   // By the time we hit the 'text-change' event, 
   // quill.getContents() will return the updated
   // content of the document
   const currentOps = quill.getContents();
   updateDatabase(currentOps);
});

function updateDatabase(currentOps) {
  // Do whatever you need to do with the current ops 
  // to store them. No need at all to store the diffs.
}
```